# Getting all the selected cells values

Tags: ios, uitableview

My purpose is when the user click on a button in `view1` (to go to the `view2`), i will send all the selected cells from `UITableView` just checked in `view1` to the `view2`.
So before passing the table to next view, i wanted to test if i am on the right track, but seems not. This is my code:

```
-(IBAction)goToView2{
    //get all section selectioned items into an array
    themesChosed=[tView indexPathsForSelectedRows];//tView is the outlet of my UITableView and themesChosed is an NSArray declared in the .h file
    for (int i=0; i<=[themesChosed count]; i++) {
        NSLog(@"%i",[[themesChosed objectAtIndex:i]integerValue]);
    }


}
```

This always returning me a single 0.

```
2012-01-13 15:52:06.472 MyApp[876:11603] 0
```

Although i selected several items on the table.

Comment: What does NSLog(@"%d", themesChosed.count); show?  Is this the same as the number of selected items in the tableview?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The objects in `themesChosed` are `NSIndexPath` objects. You'll want to access the `row` and `section` properties like so:

```
-(IBAction)goToView2{
    //get all section selectioned items into an array
    themesChosed=[tView indexPathsForSelectedRows];//tView is the outlet of my UITableView and themesChosed is an NSArray declared in the .h file
    for (int i=0; i<=[themesChosed count]; i++) {
        NSIndexPath *thisPath = [themesChosed objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"row = %i, section = %i", thisPath.row, thisPath.section);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanx for your answer, actually, what ever section i select and no matter how much row i select, i keep always getting 0: `row = 0, section = 0
`

Comment: It means one of two things 1) your tView outlet is not hooked up like you think it is, or 2) no rows are selected.

Answer (score 2):

First `NSIndexPath` is not an integer, it is an object with row and section methods, so that is probably why you get a zero. Are you sure you have `allowsMultipleSelection` set to YES?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not getting index values then best approach wound be as below to access index number:

```
  NSArray *indexes = [self.tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];
   for (NSIndexPath *path in indexes) {
     NSUInteger index = [path indexAtPosition:[path length] - 1];
     [selectedOptionsArray addObject:[optionHolderArray objectAtIndex:index]];
  }
```